# Is it possible to tile a numpy array in 2 dimensions with a single call

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array

```
a = array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

What I want is

```
array([[1,1,2,2],
       [1,1,2,2],
       [3,3,4,4],
       [3,3,4,4]])
```

I can do this with 2 calls to `numpy.repeat`

```
repeat(repeat(a,2,axis=0),2,axis=1)
```

But is there some combination of parameters to do this with a single call?

Comment: Just in case anyone was interested, the use case for this was taking subsampled U and V channels from an Android camera preview and crudely upsampling it to full resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such array using `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided()`:

```
s = min(a.strides)
as_strided(a, shape=(2,2,2,2), strides=(2*s,0,s,0)).reshape(4,4)
#array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
#       [1, 1, 2, 2],
#       [3, 3, 4, 4],
#       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

The `reshape()` is copying the data, creating a continuous array at the end.

**NOTE**: despite it is possible to do it in a single call, your original solution is 4X faster on my computer.

Comment: Thanks. It's no major issue to use 2 calls to 'repeat', I was just curious.